Can someone create a company just to access business-only services?
An individual, A, wants to, for its own individual use, buy a car at a professional-only auction without a 3rd party agent/intermediary to avoid fees.
Can they create a company for the purpose of accessing that auction, not intending to do anything else with it, letting it dormant the rest of the time? Making it exist on paper only basically?
Would the transaction need to be done through the business or can it be dealt directly by A, bypassing the company books?

@o.m. I have no jurisdiction tag, so it's open floor for answers, I am not looking for a specific jurisdiction

@littleadv Do you really think the auction would go into detail? The phrase "for commercial use" appears in many legal documents, such as software licenses, and I rarely see an explicit definition. It seems like everyone just assumes a commonly-understood definition.

The answer depends upon the rules of the auction which aren't disclosed in the question.

@Barmar maybe the auction, maybe the losing bidders, but if someone feels harmed they most definitely can go into details

I wonder about the point of "professional-only" auctions? Why would the person selling the items care who buys them?

@Barmar: E.g. because of consumer protection laws (warranty, liability). If selling across borders within the EU, B2B can also be much easier in terms of VAT.

@o.m. This will take a while though, but the car sale will stay legal even if the tax office decides that it was a hobby and in consequence, taxes have to be payed for costs that were claimed as business expense. (And potentially that VAT has to be unravelled.) (Which two are the more usual reasons why people think about forming a "fake" company)

@Barmar At professional-only auctions you can trade titleless cars, electronics with personal data...

@NicolasFormichella that sounds like a regulatory compliance that may also require licensing

@WeatherVane Indeed, but that's not the point of the question, the point of the question is can a company be formed with the sole purpose of existing on paper only

@ohwilleke I disagree, auction rules have nothing to do with my question, the question (that I just edited to clarify) is whether you can create a company for it to exist on paper with no activity or just a single resale

@NicolasFormichella You can create shell or single purpose companies without a doubt. Whether these companies qualify to bid at such a sale is not at all clear.

While forming a UK company to access business services is not inherently illegal, it must be done with a genuine and lawful intent to conduct business, either now or in the future. Misrepresenting the purpose of a company or using it to evade laws, deceive others ...

Shelf Company
australia
Can you have a company that does nothing?
Yes.

A shelf company is a company that is already registered but has never traded or conducted business and holds no assets or liabilities. Essentially, the company is registered to sit on a ‘shelf’, waiting for someone to buy it.

While it has become much easier to register a company in recent years, with the process happening electronically and taking less than a day, it is still a lot of work to get all the details right. So, buying a shelf company from a business who has already set up different classes of shares, drafted workable rules, etc. is still the most common way people start a company.
So, there is nothing wrong with owning a company that does nothing.
But what you propose isn’t “commercial” and is possibly fraud
A non-trading company isn’t engaging in commercial activity so, if that is what the auction requires, then your plan appears to involve deliberately misrepresenting the facts to obtain a commercial benefit: the textbook definition of fraud.
